# Shared hosting ip address

Tags: dns, ip, domain, sharing, shared-hosting

i would like to know how a shared hosting ip works.. for example
when we want to access the website "abc.com" and the DNS return with its IP address (1.1.1.1)..

however IP 1.1.1.1 is is a shared IP with domain "cde.com" and "efg.com", so when our browser surf to 1.1.1.1 , how do the hosting company know which domain we are looking for since there are 3 domains (abc.com, cde.com, efg.com) in ip 1.1.1.1 ?

appreciated help.. thank you..

Comment: When you signed for the hosting you provided your domain.  Typically multiple domains would cost more contact your provider and specific instructions

Answer (score 2):

An HTTP request includes a header that defines the host that it wants to retrieve.  The server is configured to use that header to lookup server the appropriate content.  Also see [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) for HTTPS requests

Comment: so what you meant is that after our PC got an IP from DNS, with the HTTP get or post request, it will include the domain name and send to the said IP address, thereafter the hosting company will then look up the domain name and refer direct to it .. am i right ? 
by the way, is it only apply to http/s request ? if i conducting a port scan on the said IP, it is actually scanning on the ports of the IP itself and not the website rite ?